# Alt + Tab is not working in gnome shell at ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 and running gnome-shell. So far almost everything went fine, but Alt + Tab is not working. How can I get Alt + Tab working? or there is some other alternative?

Comment: This has been reported as a bug [already on LaunchPad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/971051) Bugs are [offtopic](http://askubuntu.com/faq) on this site

Answer (score 19):

1. Search the Ubuntu Software Center for "CompizConfig" or
   `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Launch CompizConfig Settings Manager by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and running `ccsm`. (This may also be run from a Terminal.)
3. Click "Window Management"
4. Enable either "Application Switcher" or "Static Application Switcher"

Lance's graphical guide: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkvD7.png

**Edit**: My answer sucked, but it was the only one. However, Lance's comment was helpful to many, so I changed my answer for future searchers.

Comment: Tried this, still not working. Hoping there will be a fix very soon for this bug.

Comment: try this: activate the application switcher in compiz http://imgur.com/8LzO2

Comment: @LanceRushing: Thanks a lot :) Enabling application switcher solves the issue for Gnome Classic session. Just for a note, Alt + Tab works fine in Gnome Classic (No effects) without any modification.

Comment: This did not work for me on gnome-classic (same setting otherwise). The static window manager seems seems to be in conflict with metacity. I had to remove CCSM and reinstall gnome to get things on working condition again.

Comment: now Ubuntu 13 :) I get CompizConfig to start fine but I don't have "application switcher" showing up in the possibilities...

Comment: OK the following link must be a better place to talk about this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/971051

Comment: worked perfectly :)